# Apollo partial data behaviour in React

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

This is the only docs I can find: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#partial-data-with-graphql-errors

I noticed the first time I execute a query that returns partial data, I get the `data` and `error`:

```
  const { data, error } = useQuery(QUERY, { errorPolicy: 'all' });
```

The second time I execute the same query, it reads from the InMemoryCache. Apollo returns the `data` but never again `error` details. `. I imagine the error response is not cached. However, there is no way to tell if something went wrong.

Is there a way to tell Apollo to immediately invalidate the cache when a partial response contains errors so next time it goes out of the network to try again?

Additionally, could we have further docs describing the behavior when:

- the whole query succeeds
- when partially succeeds
- alternatives to retry next time
- useQuery variable outputs when reading from local cache

Comment: the question is did the second query succeed? If so, then why you would expect you can get error message

Comment: The second one returns the data but not the error. There is no way to display an error message since the error is null the second time. There are now two different response values for the first and subsequent calls. The problem is there is no out-of-box way to tell the cache to go to the server the next time. A quick hack is to save the previous error and configure the `fetchPolicy` based o that. I was expecting something already supported by AC3. 
The docs don't have much around partial data.

Comment: It seems like you want to have all fetch results with its own error status if I don't get it wrong, which I believe it's probably impossible since the prev will be overwrote by the lastest if you don't do some custom "hack". But if you just want to make action upon the prev result. Maybe https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` is something you are looking for.https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/src/core/networkStatus.ts#L4

Comment: I don't think `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange ` is applicable since there is not network calls. The cache is used.

Comment: I expected consistency. If I call the same query multiple times and get the same result. this is not happening for `Partial Response/Data`  with an error.